# Fetching Album Ids from facebook account using graph api is working for developer account not for others

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I tried to fetch the albums from facebook but I am getting null response from the facebook server. while I am using developer account its working fine but for others users  its not working.Can anyone help me?

I am using the below code :

```
FB.login(function (response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
            getFbUserData(callback);
        } 
    }, { 'scope': 'id,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,picture,birthday,user_photos' });
function getFbUserData(callback) {
    FB.api('/me', { locale: 'en_US', fields: 'id,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,picture,birthday,user_photos' },
    function (response) {
        callback(response);       
    });
}
 FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                var userId = FB.getAuthResponse()['userID'];
                FB.api(
                        "/" + userId + "/albums",
                        { fields: 'id,cover_photo,user_photos' },
                        function (albumResponse) {                           
                            alert(JSON.stringify(albumResponse));
                        }
                    );
                });
            }
});
```